# Don’t want to change background color at the time of dragging plotly graph

Tags: plotly

When I dragging plotly area graph that time I want to fill area with our choice color which dragging by mouse. I don't want background color which is coming by default at the time of dragging. I referred [this code](https://plot.ly/javascript/filled-area-plots/)

When I dragging graph that time graph is coming like this:
[image]

I want apposite to above image.

Here, when I dragging graph by mouse that time dragged area filling by gray color and remain area of graph is filling by some light color. I don't want like this.

Hope, you will understand my problem.

My code is:

```
<script>
var trace1 = {
x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2016-10-06 22:23:00',  '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-07 22:23:00','2013-12-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-08 22:23:00'],
y: [1, 3, 6,9, 4, 5],
  fill: 'tozeroy',
  fillcolor: 'red',
  text: server1,
  hoverinfo: "x+y+text",
  name:"Server 1",
  type: 'scatter',
  mode:"markers",
  marker:
  {
    size:5,
    color:"gray"
  },
  uid:"c2e171"
};
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 20,
    r: 40,
    b: 40,
    t: 10
  },
  legend: {
    "orientation": "h"
  },
  yaxis : {fixedrange: true},
};
var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data,layout);

var plotDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout',
function(eventdata){  
    alert( 'ZOOM!' + '\n\n' +
        'Event data:' + '\n' + 
         JSON.stringify(eventdata) + '\n\n' +
        'x-axis start:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]'])+ '\n' +
        'x-axis end:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']));
        var xVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]']);
        var yVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "dragging plotly area graph"?

Comment: Yes @Maximilian Peters. Actually When I dragging graph that time by default background color is filling. I don't want this.

Comment: I don't understand too what you mean with "dragging plotly area graph"? Can you explain the not desired behaviour in simplier, detailed words? Do you mean the zoom mode, that leads to left and right of your zoom selection changes to gray background?

Comment: @flipperweid, I edited my post. and I explain in detail. Please give me solution.

Comment: @AnilJagtap I don't get it. "When I will drag graph by mouse that time I want to fill area by color which dragged by mouse "? Maybe you want to disable the zoom mode?

Comment: @flipperweid, I want zoom mode also. Whatever you can able to see in picture like two part with shadow, i want middle part only like shadow. Remaining two parts has to be normal.

Comment: @AnilJagtap Ah ok, now I understand you. The middle part should have the shadow and part right and left of the selection should not have the shadow. Sorry I think this isn't supported by the library:/ The only way is to modify the library code..

Comment: @flipperweid, Thank you, can you tell me which library and how to modify it?

Comment: @AnilJagtap I mean the plotly.js-library. I think it's complex and I don't know how to modify it. I think you should accept the current behaviour - its intuitive enough in my view

Comment: @AnilJagtap did you get any solution for this? I also want to achieve this.

Comment: @Grovile no. I didn't get any solution for this